# What does {expires_at: 0} mean is debug_token response?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here is a response to my attempt to validate user's `access_token`.

```
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": 409277239141609,
        "is_valid": true,
        "application": "Les \u00e2mes vagabondes",
        "user_id": 100003752867359,
        "issued_at": 1353410808,
        "expires_at": 0,
        "scopes": ["create_note", "email", "manage_pages", "photo_upload", "publish_actions", "publish_stream", "share_item", "status_update", "user_birthday", "user_interests", "user_likes", "user_photos", "video_upload"]
    }
}
```

It says that the `access_token` is valid, though does not give the `expires_at` timestamp. How do I get the `expires_at` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Little late to the party.. but I guess it means the `access_token` does not expire (eg. you're the developer of the Facebook App).

Comment: so if i login using my facebook which is my developer account, it always returns 0 but any other user will get some value?

Comment: Recently I realized that the response of "debug_token" (v3.1 API) call no longer contains "expires_at", yet "is_valid" remains "true"  I suspect that the developer (app) token never expires

Answer (score -3):

It means that the access token you have can no longer be used because of reasons such as the password change, etc. so that you should get a new access token.